# A conformal map problem

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I have done the first question by proving that $z^3=a+bi$ has 3 roots but don't have ideas on the second question about proving perpendicular. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: What are the real and imaginary parts of $z^3$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z = x+iy$ where $x,y\in\mathbb R$.
\begin{align}
z^3 & = {} \overbrace{(x+iy)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2iy + 3xi^2y^2 + i^3y^3}^{\text{binomial theorem}} \\[10pt]
& = (x^3 -3xy^2) + i(3x^2y - y^3)
\end{align}
So here's a bit of a "trick": you need to recognize that the two polynomials they give you are the real and imaginary parts of $z^3$.  When you say $x^3-3xy^2=a$ and $3x^2y - y^3=b$, you're saying $z^3=a+bi$.  So $x$ is the real part and $y$ the imaginary part of a cube root of $a+bi$.  The curves $x=\text{constant}$ and $y=\text{constant}$ are straight lines meeting at right angles.  Therefore their images under the cubing function are curves that meet at right angles --- that's where the conformal nature of this mapping is used.

Comment: But we need to prove the curves $x^3-3xy^2=a$ and $3x^2y-y^3=b$ are perpendicular at their intersection points. You introduce x=constant and y=constant and what is the next step?

Comment: @Gatsby : As I said, "that is where the CONFORMAL nature of this mapping is used" (emphasis added).  Do you understand what "conformal" means?  If so, that should answer your question. $\qquad$

Comment: @I understand what "conformal" means, but are you sure that $x^3-3xy^2=a$ and $ 3x^2y-y^3=b$ are the images of $x=c1, y=c2$ under the function$f(z)=z^3$?

Comment: @Gatsby : $\ldots\,$and those curves $x=c_1$, $y=c_2$ are straight lines meeting at right angles.  Since the function is conformal, their images under the function meet at the same angles. $\qquad$

Comment: At beginning I mistakenly regard $3x^2y-y^3=b$ and $x^3-3xy^2=a$ as images of $f(z)=z^3$ but in fact they are preimages of $f(z)=z^3$. No my confuse is waived, thank you!